# Jquery Returing HTML as a object or array

Tags: jquery, html, filter, get

So I have a html doc with about 20 divs with the class 'event'.

```
rows = $(data).filter('.event');
alert(rows.length); //returns 20
alert(rows.html()); // only returns first result
```

What I want to do is get the html in an object or array so I can loop through and every 3rd one wrap a div around them, the problem is rows.html() only returns the first result but rows.length is correct.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to build an array from the HTML content of your elements:

```
var htmlContentArray = rows.map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

However, if you only want to wrap the contents of every third row, you can simply use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) with the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector:

```
$(data).filter(".event:nth-child(3n)").wrapInner("<div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
rows.each(function(index, element)) {
  // Your code goes here
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

In order to iterate each element of a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery tries to convert/interpret html code if you wrap `$( )` around it, so try to do `$(rows.html())`.
Then iterate:

```
$.each(rows, function(index, value) {
    // Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rows is array so you should iterate

```
for(var i=0; i<rows.length(); i++){
 rows[i].html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
var arr = jQuery.map(rows, function (item) { 
  return $(item).html(); 
});
```